# How to forced run the profile pictures sync with Exchange High-Res Photo option

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, picture-library, exchange-server, synchronization

How to force the run the profile pictures sync with Exchange High-Res Photo option ([link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jenstr/2012/08/17/using-exchange-2013-high-resolution-photos-from-sharepoint-server-2013/)) and SharePoint UPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It isn't based on a timer job, it is based on an HTTP module with the user visiting a site that renders their own photo.

Comment: But maybe some kind of script which will pull these pics from exchange server and run Set-UserPhoto cmdlet?

Comment: You could develop a custom solution that queried `https://exchangeserver.example.com/s/GetUserPhoto?email=jane.doe@example.com&size=HR648x648`, resize all of the pictures (S, M, L), and then set the user profile to point to that picture. But that defeats the purpose of integrating with Exchange.